# How to Pass Azure Devops Parameters to pscore script

Tags: powershell, azure-devops, azure-powershell, powershell-core

```
parameters:
  - name: BlobURL
    type: string
    default: ""

    stages:
      - stage: ProcessMetaDataFile
        displayName: 'Process'
        jobs:
          - job: Upload 
            displayName: upload
        steps:
          - checkout: self
          - pwsh: ./psscript.ps1 
               env: { Cont: "my Test",BlobURL: ???BlobURL }
```

Above is the script:
I want to pass yaml parameter to pwsh script.
tried ${{parameters.BlobURL}}  ${parameters.BlobURL}
$[parameters.BlobURL] '${parameters.BlobURL}'

None worked so far

Tried this as well https://daniel-krzyczkowski.github.io/Parameters-In-Azure-DevOps-Pipelines/  but no success

Answer (score 1):

Both `'${{ parameters.BlobURL }}'` and `"${{ parameters.BlobURL }}"` are correct. Just make sure the expression is inside of a string.

Also check your indentation: "steps" needs to be on the same column as "displayName":

```
parameters:
  - name: BlobURL
    type: string
    default: ""

stages:
- stage: ProcessMetaDataFile
  displayName: 'Process'
  jobs:
    - job: Upload 
      displayName: upload
      steps:
        - checkout: self
        - pwsh: ./psscript.ps1 
          env: { Cont: "my Test", BlobURL: '${{ parameters.BlobURL }}' }
```

Comment: Thanks Manuel. This not worked though. I changed pwsh to powershell@2 for now and moved ahead.